# Error: No class Def found error while setting up Java as a Windows Service

Tags: java, windows-services, classpath

Following is the error log I'm getting:
[image]

I'm using

> wrapper-windows-x86-32-3.5.25-pro

in order to make my already developed application in Spring-boot. I wanted to execute this application as a windows service but I'm not.

This problem is specific to [Tanukisoftware](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/index.html) as I'm unable to configure it.

PFB the configuration I'm using for setting up the class path here:

```
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrappertest.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5
wrapper.java.classpath.4=../lib/myApp.jar
```

even if myApp.jar contains the slf4j classpath already and its running already. I think this is library specific problem and its not finding up the classpath even if I explicitly set it like did above.

Can you please let me know how it can be solved?

Comment: Could you see if there is some process / service that you need to stop before it takes your latest configurations in wrapper.conf? 
A re-build maybe ?
Clueless about the environment for Tanuki, hence being a little obtuse about this.

Comment: The problem that I have encountered is that this library is not picking up the first import related to slf4j.

Comment: Do you package your application as JAR file? If so, is **slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar** in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in the `Class-Path` property ?
How do the dependencies get to `../lib` folder? Did you manually copied them there?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try building a fat jar of your application ? You can add following lines to your Spring Boot project's `pom.xml` to repackage jar file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Besides, your following property line seems invalid:

```
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5
```

Is it pointing a jar file actually ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to fat the jar of my application - Its already working fine except running it as a service. I will try your solution here and let you know. To your question - Is it pointing a jar file actually? -> Yes, its pointing to only a jar file - developed by mvn package command.
I tried wrapper.java.classpath.3 ... here because it wasn't picking up the classpath already set inside the jar file made. So, I tried to explicitly pass it. I know it is invalid but just to draw your attention here that even after I specified it explicitly in the class path its still not picking up..

Comment: I see. For maven configuration, you can check this link either: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html

Answer (score 2):

slf4j-api-1.7.5 should have a .jar extension. That is possibly confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

Also, even just as a debugging step, try running your Windows service using [Apache ProcRun](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) to see if your results are any different.